# Error when running reshape on image. dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

[image]

I am trying to reshape the image so as to run gan models but I get this error.

AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'reshape

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to utilize a Tensorflow Dataset with an existing Keras example. In this case, you'll need to use a map function to achieve the image resize and conversion to grayscale which would match the MNIST input shape I believe you're going for. This example below should show you how to accomplish this in your code.

```
a = tf.ones([180,180,3])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(a)

# Note, how we're first using tf.image.resize to reduce the image size to 28x28 and then using rgb_to_grayscale to convert from 3 channels into 1.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(tf.image.resize(x, (28,28))))
```